# Using jquery to populate select options from MySQL

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I think I'm pretty close, and am just missing something really simple.  I've tried a few different ways of doing this, after doing a lot of reading here and other sites, but haven't gotten anything to work.  All I get is a select box with no options under it.

This is the most recent version, though I've tried a couple other 'flavors'.

Here's my php

```
<?php
require_once 'login.php';
$conn = mysqli_connect($db_hostname, $db_username, $db_password, $db_database) or die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());

$sql = "select typecode, typename from bottletypes";
$query = mysqli_query($conn, $sql) or die ("listBottles102.php: get types");
$data = array();
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query, true)){
    $data[] = $row; 
};
echo json_encode($data);
```

And here is my html

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>    
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
          var items="";
          $.getJSON("getTypes.php",function(data){
            $.each(data,function(index,item) 
            {
              items+="<option value='"+item.typecode+"'>"+item.typename+"</option>";
            });
            $("#bottleTypes").html(items); 
          });
        });
    </script>

    <select id="bottleTypes">
      <option>Default</option>
    </select>
```

Like I said, I'm sure this is pretty simple.  And I'm sure there are numerous other ways to do this.  Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Have you console.log(data) to make sure it is in the format you think it is in?

Comment: I had not tried that, no.  I ran through the console messages, and found a different piece of script, somewhere unrelated, that was causing an error.  I commented that set of script out, and now my issue here appears to be resolved.  Now I need to go back and figure out why that script was not working, and causing an issue for this script, but not others.  Regardless, I believe that this is now resolved.  Thanks for the hint; it's those little things that really help those of us who are trying to teach ourselves how all of this works.  Thanks Kevin.

Comment: I believe you need to parse the response to json object, instead of using it as a string